# Is there a way to generate a single MSI token for a list of Azure resources?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have list of services registered in Azure AD. Is there a way to generate a single MSI token by passing list of MSI ApplicatonIds and generate a token which has all the ids in the audience field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. One token will only include one audience.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using an interactive authentication flow, you can use the *refresh token* associated with the token for one audience, to get a token for another audience. This means you only have to authenticate once.

[From the v1.0 docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code)

> Access Tokens are short-lived and must be refreshed after they expire to continue accessing resources. You can refresh the access_token by submitting another POST request to the `/token` endpoint, but this time providing the refresh_token instead of the code. Refresh tokens are valid for all resources that your client has already been given consent to access - thus, a refresh token issued on a request for `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com` can be used to request a new access token for `resource=https://contoso.com/api`.

[From the v2.0 docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

> Access_tokens are short lived, and you must refresh them after they expire to continue accessing resources. You can do so by submitting another POST request to the `/token` endpoint, this time providing the refresh_token instead of the code. Refresh tokens are valid for all permissions that your client has already received consent for - thus, a refresh token issued on a request for `scope=mail.read` can be used to request a new access token for `scope=api://contoso.com/api/UseResource`.